# Are the WordPress install docs wrong?

Tags: wordpress, installation, documentation

I'm following the docs at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/

I downloaded 5.17 in a zip file from https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/releases, unzipped it and renamed it `civicrm` (I need 5.17 and not 5.18 for various reasons).

The docs say:

> You should now have a /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm
>   directory containing civicrm.php, README.txt and another civicrm
>   directory (which in turn contains bin, CRM, sql, templates, etc.).

The unzipped `civicrm` directory does not contain civicrm.php at the top level; that file is in a folder called `install`. There is no directory inside `civicrm` called `civicrm`. As a result, the CiviCRM plugin does not show up in WordPress admin to be activated, even with correct `_www` and 755 permissions.

Do I create a directory inside `civicrm`? How do I get the plugin to show up in WP admin?

And, using the plugin installer in WP Admin to upload the zip file `civicrm-core-5.17.zip` directly results in the error `The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.`

Answer (score 3):

Is there somewhere in the docs where it says to go to https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/releases because that isn't the right place to download and all you get from there is core, not the wordpress parts, so if it says that it should get changed.

You need to download from https://civicrm.org/download and if you need an older release you can go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/files/civicrm-stable/

Comment: The docs say to download from https://civicrm.org/download  so they are correct.

Comment: The WordPress docs need to be clarified; sourceforge has the older releases as WP plugins, while civicrm.org/download only has the most recent release as a WP plugin. Github does not have zips of the WP plugins.

Comment: There might be a reason sourceforge isn't mentioned since Civi is superquick to drop support for old versions and so the docs might purposely encourage only installing the latest version. Github isn't mentioned because it's only used for development and the very first link at the top of the wordpress install doc says what to do if you want to install for development. So it might be more confusing to add github references to the sysadmin docs.

Comment: True; docs can be more confusing if they seek to cover every possibility.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get a different version of the wordpress download you can just swap in the relevant version number in the url

for example -> https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.17.0-wordpress.zip